# Convert Matrix4 to a Float64List in Dart/Fluter

Tags: flutter, dart, matrix, flutter-animation

In Flutter the transform method for path requires at Float64List to represent a Matrix4. How can one convert a Matrix4 into a Float64List to be used in path.transform()?

Flutter Path Transform:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/transform.html

Comment: use `Matrix4.storage`

Answer (score 2):

As @pskink commented, Matrix4d.storage returns at Float64List.